# plainToClass to call object.method() in web worker thread

Tags: angular, web-worker, reflect-metadata

I am using angular, trying to pass an object to the web worker for the background process.
the class is

```
Article{
  method1();
  propertyA;
}
```

```
addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  // if without plainToClass, how to call article.method1()
  data.article=plainToClass(Article, data.article);
  console.log(data.article.method1());
});
```

Because in the web worker thread, I want to use article.method1(),

1. After the object is passed to web worker, it becomes an object that does not have methods but only properties. Why is this? pass as a string?
2. Tried to use `plainToClass()` to convert the passed obj to an Object with method, which in main thread I am able to do so, load string and convert to Class object. but in web worker, it complains about `Reflect.getMetadata is not a function`. Which seems it cannot find the imported `import 'reflect-metadata'` in `polyfills.ts`

Answer:

It turns out I need to import this in Article class file

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
export class Article implements Clonable{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data to a Web worker is done by [serializing the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#transferring_data_to_and_from_workers_further_details), so you won't be able to pass in behavior. Instead, you'll need to either use `plainToClass` as you have in your example, or you can provide the functionality in a helper function.

Additionally, `import reflect-metadata` is an import for side-effects. This code is [run once per context](https://web.dev/module-workers/#enter-module-workers), so it will need to be run again *inside the worker*, and then `plainToClass` should work.

That said, a simpler approach might be to try to call the class constructor using the values passed in - if that’s possible?

Comment: How to import reflect metadata in web worker in angular? Thanks

Comment: It turns out I need to import this in the Article class file
`
import 'reflect-metadata';
export class Article implements Clonable{
}
`